# Where to change JDK compile level in Intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

I got this error.

And I setting in Intellij Idea is Below:

[image]

[image]

Where to set the Language level. Why Idea use -source 1.5?

Comment: did you restart intellij after you changed, the project language version ? You can also try to do an invalidate caches

Comment: Yes, I restart many times.  And how to do an invalidate caches?

Comment: Go to file menu > invalidate caches

Comment: Also check the pom.xml if you're using maven.

Comment: only   <java-version>1.7</java-version>  in my pom.xml

Comment: I do invalidate caches, Issue still there.

Comment: Issue resolved,  vikingsteve notice me, I re-open the project and choose delete existing project and re-import again. the issue resolved.

Comment: Maybe it's BUG for intellij idea.